# Match repeated patterns in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string

I am trying to find all strings that follows a specific pattern in a python string.

```
"\[\[Cats:.*\]\]"
```

However if many occurrences of such pattern exist together on a line in a string it sees the pattern as just one, instead of taking the patterns separately.

```
strng = '[[Cats: Text1]] said I am in the [[Cats: Text2]]fhg is abnorn'
x = re.findall("\[\[Cats:.*\]\]", strng)
```

The output gotten is:

```
['[[Cats: Text1]] said I am in the [[Cats: Text2]]']
```

instead of

```
['[[Cats: Text1]]', '[[Cats: Text2]]']
```

which is a list of lists.

What regex do I use?

Comment: `"\[\[Cats:.*?\]\]"`

Comment: Try `\[\[Cats:.*?\]\]`

Answer (score 1):

`"\[\[Cats:.*?\]\]"`

Your current regex is greedy - it's gobbling up EVERYTHING, from the first open brace to the last close brace. Making it non-greedy should return all of your results.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2VLrzg/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The problom is that you are doing a greedy search, add a ? after .* to get a non greedy return.

code follows:

```
import re

strng = '[[Cats: Text1]] said I am in the [[Cats: Text2]]fhg is abnorn'
regex_template = re.compile(r'\[\[Cats:.*?\]\]') 
matches = re.findall(regex_template, strng)
print(matches)
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't do .*, because that will never terminate. .* means any character and not even one occurence is required.

```py
import re

strng = '''[[Cats: lol, this is 100 % cringe]] 
said I am in the [[Cats: lol, this is 100 % cringe]] 
fhg is abnorn'''

x = re.findall(r"\[\[Cats: [^\]]+\]\]", strng) 
print(x)
```

Comment: Regex fails if the string inside the brackets contains a close bracket. Also misleading in that `.*` "terminates" just fine.